# Check MAC address of a device on the other end of an Ethernet cable

Tags: ethernet

Assuming I have a machine with Windows / Mac / Linux OS installed that's connected via Ethernet to an unknown device (e.g.: router, another computer, LAN printer), how can I figure out that device's MAC address?

Comment: Somewhat similar to this question:  http://superuser.com/questions/302057/find-an-unknown-static-ip-subnet-mask-of-device I strongly installing wireshark, and simply monitoring the link.

Comment: Thank you! I just used Wireshark as you suggested and logged the ARP protocol traffic. It told me everything I needed to know. Please turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Send a broadcast If you don't have any information of the other end, just send a `ping 255.255.255.255`, it will send a broadcast ping (IP 255.255.255.255) with broadcast MAC address (FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF) which will be sent to all devices on the network, even if you are connected to a switch (which don't filter those requests, of course).

Answer (score -2):

[NMAP](http://nmap.org/) can scan your network and tell you ***a lot*** about what is on your network, including MAC address.  It might even be able to tell you just what that unknown device is.

Nmap ("Network Mapper") is a free and open source (license) utility for network discovery and security auditing. Many systems and network administrators also find it useful for tasks such as network inventory, managing service upgrade schedules, and monitoring host or service uptime. Nmap uses raw IP packets in novel ways to determine what hosts are available on the network, what services (application name and version) those hosts are offering, what operating systems (and OS versions) they are running, what type of packet filters/firewalls are in use, and dozens of other characteristics. It was designed to rapidly scan large networks, but works fine against single hosts. Nmap runs on all major computer operating systems, and official binary packages are available for Linux, Windows, and Mac OS X. In addition to the classic command-line Nmap executable, the Nmap suite includes an advanced GUI and results viewer (Zenmap), a flexible data transfer, redirection, and debugging tool (Ncat), a utility for comparing scan results (Ndiff), and a packet generation and response analysis tool (Nping).

Comment: What exactly are you planning on scanning with nmap since this is an **unknown device**?

Comment: @Zoredache Obviously, you havent used NMAP before.  His exact situation is what people use NMAP for.  It can scan the entire NETWORK via a variety of methods and report back all its findings.  Hell, I used NMAP *today* to get a list of all the devices, IPs, and MACs of the machines on my network.

Comment: I have used nmap frequently.  For the most part it assumes a functioning IP network configuration  If you just plug your computer into a **random unknown device** like you might get out of a garage sale the network will not be properly configured.  What options are you planning on using that to scan the device.  Without a proper configuration how will the replies get back to you.  If this is so easy, why not update your answer with some actual details of exactly how you would do this instead of just a copy and past of the description of the application.