# Find MAC address of a device on the other end of an Ethernet cable

Tags: networking, ethernet, mac-address

Before anyone points it out, this is a different question to [Check MAC address of a device on the other end of an Ethernet cable](https://superuser.com/questions/789355/check-mac-address-of-a-device-on-the-other-end-of-an-ethernet-cable).

I'm interested in an automated way (rather than [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), etc) of finding **only** the MAC address of the device on the other end of an ethernet cable, rather than mapping the entire network. Is this even possible?

Update: The scenario is that my user has several boxes running embedded Linux connected to a network along with other equipment. I can figure out how those boxes are connected to each other by detecting the MAC or IP address each one is connected to.

Comment: You ask for MAC or IP address. Does a tracert to a known address off network and grabbing the ip address of the first hop work for you?

Comment: No, because I can't guarantee the network is connected to the internet.

Comment: Then tracert to the DHCP server?

Comment: I can't guarantee there is a DHCP server.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228776/get-mac-address-of-a-directly-connected-device

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're talking about doing this from a PC, by looking at the ARP table you should be able to find the MAC address you're looking for. Of course, you also need to know the devices IP address so you're looking at the right one.

The command you want to use in cmd is `arp -a`

Comment: I know I can find the MAC from the IP address. What I'm looking for is some way of finding either from just the physical connection.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "finding either from just the physical connection"

Comment: I've updated the question, hopefully this makes it clearer.