# Accessing web interface on Allied Telesyn GS950/24 Managed Switch

Tags: networking

Okay, so I purchased an used Allied Telesyn GS950/24 a couple days ago and have been struggling with it since. Seller said the device worked flawlessly. Now, the device does actually work as switch, as it does indeed transmit data.

However, I can't seem to access the Web UI this device comes with, and is actually the reason I purchased it. Apparently 192.168.1.1/24 is the default network setting but the device does not respond to any browser, ping or nmap. I have set my subnet to match but had no success. Seller says he did not change the default settings. I even tried both Windows and Linux and still nothing.

I got a new RS232 cable and plugged it to my computer and the switch but there does not seem to be any communication. Screen shows no output, even after power cycling the device.

I opened it up and everything seems to be fine. Could there be any reset switches I can use to make the device reset to factory defaults, just in case?

Any clues on what to try next? I purchased this device as-is, I should have probably asked the seller to show me how to access the UI but I just did not.

Update: my device is the older model, not the eco one and only two sfp instead of four.

Update 2: Tried it on my friend's computer and didn't work either. He has the same motherboard as mine though.

Update 3: Docs are at http://www.alliedtelesis.com/media/datasheets/guides/s79_ug_a_v100.pdf

Update 4: I might have been getting mixed up with the newer version. It turns out that the device either gets an IP address via a DHCP server connected to it OR uses a preconfigured IP address. So the question now is: How can I find out what's its IP address?

Update 5: Can't get its IP address. First of all, I have no clue what its subnet might be. Tried pinging broadcast and checking the ARP tables but it's not there. Tried monitoring traffic with wireshark but only one packet is sent and it's EAP - no IP address there. I have the MAC address but can't seem to make use of it. Tried haneWIN's LLDP agent but couldn't get it to work. Arping is no help either.

Update 6: I am afraid my question has turned into this one: [Find an unknown static IP + subnet mask of device?](https://superuser.com/questions/302057/find-an-unknown-static-ip-subnet-mask-of-device)

Thanks a bunch !

Answer (score 1):

I think you have reached a dead end. Even if you knew the IP address, you still would not be able to log in since you do not know the set user name and password. The switch apparently is not in its factory default state.

As far as discovering the IP address of the switch, the manual states:

> When the DHCP feature is enabled, a DHCP server automatically assigns
>   an IP address which is not advertised over the network. As a
>   consequence, you do not know what IP address has been assigned to the
>   switch.
>
> Fortunately, there is an ATI Web Discovery Tool available that
>   resolves this issue. It detects the MAC address, IP address and other
>   information of the AT-GS950 series switches that are present on your
>   local area network.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but apparently this tool is unable to find anything. I remember toying around with Wireshark and there was only a layer 2 packet that I could capture that had the switch Mac address. That was the only one ever captured and wasn't even a dhcp request.

Answer (score 0):

#### Are there be any reset switches I can use to make the device reset to factory defaults?

Press the front panel **eco-friendly Button** for more than 10 seconds and release it.

By pressing the button for longer than 10 seconds, you will initiate a software reboot of
the switch and reset all of the configuration parameters
of the switch to the factory default settings - including
the management IP address.

When the switch is reset to factory defaults, its IP address will
revert to 192.168.1.1.

---

#### Switch Reboot

> You can reboot the AT-GS950/24 switch by either pressing the front
> panel eco-friendly switch between 5 to 9 seconds or by using the
> Normal reboot function provided in the AT-S109 management software.
>
> In addition to rebooting the switch, you have the option to reset the
> AT-GS950/24 switch configuration parameters to the original factory
> default settings. There are two ways to accomplish this:
>
> - **Press the front panel ecofriendly button for more than 10 seconds and release it.**
> - Reboot the switch in the AT-S109 management software and follow the procedures to reset to factory defaults. See Switch Reboot and
>   Configure Factory Default Values for more information.

Source [AT-GS950/24 Web Browser User Guide](http://www.alliedtelesis.com/manuals/S109V110WEBa/Basic_Parameters.html)

---

#### eco-friendly Button

> [image]
>
> The eco-friendly button serves multiple functions. You can toggle the
> port  LEDs on and off, reboot your switch or reset your switch
> configuration to  factory default values.  The button operates as
> follows:
>
> - eco-Friendly mode - When you press the eco-friendly  button for 1 to 4 seconds, the front panel port LEDs are  either enabled or disabled.
>   You may use the button to  turn off (disable) the LEDs when you are
>   not  monitoring the switch. Toggling the LEDs does not  interfere with
>   the network operations of the switch. The  eco-friendly button does
>   not control the Power LED.
> - Reboot the switch - By pressing the button for 5 to 9  seconds, you can initiate a software reboot of the  switch.
> - Factory default reset - By pressing the button greater
>   than 10 seconds, you will initiate a software reboot of
>   the switch and reset all of the configuration parameters
>   of the switch to the factory default settings - including
>   the management IP address.
>   When the switch is reset to factory defaults, its IP address will
>   revert to 192.168.1.1. If your browser is configured for another IP
>   address, you will have to reconf
>   igure your browser and workstation
>   before you can again connect to the switch.

Source [AT-GS950/24 Web Browser User Guide](http://www.alliedtelesis.com/manuals/S109V110WEBa/Basic_Parameters.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I had already seen that, and I should have mentioned that mine is the older model and no reset switches are present.

Answer (score 0):

I have just acquired one of these switches.  You just need a simple serial crossover cable (pins 2,3,5 set) and you can access the device via the serial port on the front.  Gives a simple menu from which you can then set the IP address.